# Is there a fast alternative to scipy _norm_pdf for correlated distribution sampling?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution, montecarlo

I have fit a series of SciPy continuous distributions for a Monte-Carlo simulation and am looking to take a large number of samples from these distributions. However, I would like to be able to take correlated samples, such that the `i`th sample takes the e.g., 90th percentile from each of the distributions.

In doing this, I've found a quirk in SciPy performance:

```py
# very fast way to many uncorrelated samples of length n
for shape, loc, scale, in distro_props:
    sp.stats.norm.rvs(*shape, loc=loc, scale=scale, size=n)

# verrrrryyyyy slow way to take correlated samples of length n
correlate = np.random.uniform(size=n)
for shape, loc, scale, in distro_props:
    sp.stats.norm.ppf(correlate, *shape, loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

Most of the results about this claim that the slowness on these SciPy distros if from the type-checking etc. wrappers. However when I profiled the code, the vast bulk of the time is spent in the underlying math function `[_continuous_distns.py:179(_norm_pdf)]`[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html). Furthermore, it scales with `n`, implying that it's looping through every elemnt internally.

The SciPy [docs on rv_continuous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) almost seem to suggest that the subclass should override this for performance, but it seems bizarre that I would monkeypatch into SciPy to speed up their ppf. I would just compute this for the normal from the ppf formula, but I also use lognormal and skewed normal, which are more of a pain to implement.

So, what is the best way in Python to compute a fast ppf for normal, lognormal, and skewed normal distributions? Or more broadly, to take correlated samples from several such distributions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the second option corresponds to numbers in the right half of the distribution (since uniform is in [0, 1]). I'm surprised the first option isn't implemented as `ppf(uniform(-1, 1, size=n), loc=loc, scale=scale)`

Comment: Are you restricted to scipy? Maybe a probabilistic programming language has a faster implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this issue was caused by my use of the [skew-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) distribution. The ppf of the skew-normal actually does not have a closed-form analytic definition, so in order to compute the ppf, it fell back to `scipy.continuous_rv`'s numeric approximation, which involved iteratively computing the cdf and using that to zero in on the ppf value. The skew-normal pdf is the product of the normal pdf and normal cdf, so this numeric approximation called the normal's pdf and cdf many many times. This is why when I profiled the code, it *looked* like the normal distribution was the problem, not the SKU normal. The other answer to this question was able to achieve time savings by skipping type-checking, but didn't actually make a difference on the run-time growth, just a difference on small-n runtimes.

To solve this problem, I have replaced the skew-normal distribution with the [Johnson SU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution) distribution. It has 2 more free parameters than a normal distribution so it can fit different types of skew and kurtosis effectively. It's supported for all real numbers, and it has a closed-form ppf definition with a fast implementation in SciPy. Below you can see example Johnson SU distributions I've been fitting from the 10th, 50th, and 90th percentiles.

[image: Example distributions]

Answer (score 3):

If you need just the normal `ppf`, it is indeed puzzling that it is so slow, but you can use `scipy.special.erfinv` instead:

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
np.allclose(special.erfinv(2*x-1)*np.sqrt(2),stats.norm().ppf(x))
# True
timeit(lambda:stats.norm().ppf(x),number=1000)
# 0.7717257660115138
timeit(lambda:special.erfinv(2*x-1)*np.sqrt(2),number=1000)
# 0.015020604943856597
```

EDIT:

`lognormal` and `triangle` are also straight forward:

```
c = np.random.uniform()

np.allclose(np.exp(c*special.erfinv(2*x-1)*np.sqrt(2)),stats.lognorm(c).ppf(x))
# True

np.allclose(((1-np.sqrt(1-(x-c)/((x>c)-c)))*((x>c)-c))+c,stats.triang(c).ppf(x))
# True
```

skew normal I'm not familiar enough, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good answer for normal only, but I was hoping that I could avoid re-implementing all the distributions like this that I use. I've also got lognormal, skewed normal, and triangular. Looks like that may be the only option, but it still seems like a problem that would be well solved in the library

Comment: @NealJMD See update, not all you need, unfortunately, but almost.